# Firebase multiple "apps" - client side and server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-admin

So, I wanted to add another firebase app into the project. I already had one for SSR (firebase-admin), so server could pre-render sites. Now I want to add firebase@8, so I can start using it on client side, and later apply firestore rules to it. The problem is, when I'm trying to use it I get this error:

```
/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js:22:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-namespace.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
./firebase/config.js
./firebase/createDocument.js
./components/form/Form.js
./pages/opinia/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Here is my config file:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

// initialize firebase on CLIENT
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
};

export const clientApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// firestore
export const projectFirestoreClient = firebase.firestore(clientApp);

// timestamp
export const timestampClient = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;

// initialize firebase on SERVER
if (!admin.apps.length) {
  const serviceAccount = require('./firebase-adminsdk.json');

  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
}

// firestore
export const projectFirestoreAdmin = admin.firestore();

// timestamp
export const timestampAdmin = admin.firestore.Timestamp;
```

So, my question is, how do I fix this error? And what's causing it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Admin is not meant to be used on client side. When you run the app, Firebase Admin is also being imported and causing that error. Ideally you should initialize Firebase Admin in a different file that can be accessed on server side only.

Checkout [this blog](https://dev.to/dingran/next-js-firebase-authentication-and-middleware-for-api-routes-29m1#:%7E:text=Using%20Firebase%20Admin%20on%20Server%20Side) for step-by-step explanation on how to use Firebase Admin with NextJS.